# Is it possible to get the most liked comment of a post with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API to retrieve either:

a) likes and shares of each posts, between a given date period on a page
b) like-count of the most liked comment for each post
c) like-count of the most liked share-post for each post

Currently I can get the like and shares directly but not for comments or share-posts. I know this can be done easily via FQL, but since Facebook's shutting down FQL, that's not a very good solution. Is there a way to retrieve these informations without iterating through pages ans pages of comments/share-posts?

Comment: No. You need to fetch all and filter yourself

Comment: Yes, I have it in mind. But that would be utterly slow and terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function doublemax($mylist){ 
  $maxvalue=max($mylist); 
  while(list($key,$value)=each($mylist)){ 
    if($value==$maxvalue)$maxindex=$key; 
  } 
  return array("m"=>$maxvalue,"i"=>$maxindex); 
}
```